# Laravel Carbon date format weird in bootstrap popover

Tags: laravel-5, popover, laravel-blade, php-carbon

I'm displaying a datediff in my Laravel view (blade). I can show the time between two dates as follows:

```
$lengthOwned = Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffForHumans(new Carbon\Carbon($real_asset->real_owned_since));
echo($lengthOwned);
```

The `echo` statement displays this info correctly on my page, as does placing `{{$lengthOwned}}` anywhere in the blade. It displays like:

```
4 months after
```

for the difference between 01/03/2018 and today 05/11/2018

However, I need to display this in a bootstrap popover, and when I do I get the number, without the accompanying text. So instead of "`4 months after`" in the popover panel I just get "`4`". That means that "`4 months after`" and "`12 years after`" become just "`4`" and "`12`" - not good.

My popover code is:

```
<a href="#RE" data-toggle="popover" title="How long since acquired" data-content={{$lengthOwned}}>CLICK FOR TIME LAPSED</a>
```

with the following javaScript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
</script>
```

Anyone have any suggestions as to why the carbon-provided text is missing/truncated?

I'm running Laravel 5.5, PHP 7 with XAMPP on Windows 10

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing quotes for the value of `data-content`, right now you have:

```
<a  data-content={{$lengthOwned}}>CLICK FOR TIME LAPSED</a>
```

this would render something like the following (which sets the value of `data-content` to 4 and adds two weird attributes):

```
<a  data-content=4 months later>CLICK FOR TIME LAPSED</a>
```

Instead wrap the whole value within quotes:

```
<a  data-content="{{$lengthOwned}}">CLICK FOR TIME LAPSED</a>
```

Comment: Perfect - that was it! All I needed was the quotation marks. Many thanks :)